# How to install Java SDK on CentOS?

Tags: java, sdk, centos

I have [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 5, but I don't know the steps to install Java SDK on Linux.

Where to download the RPM file and what can I do next to fully install that?

Then I need to install [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat).

Or is there any ready-made package for all?

Comment: I suspect we need to start being clear when we mean Oracle Java, or can accept one of the open source alternatives. Sventek has a good answer - but it won't help if you have tools with maintainers that refuse to fix issues until reproduced on the Oracle Java/JDK tools.

Answer (score 166):

The following command will return a list of all packages directly related to Java. They will be in the format of `java-<version>`.

```
$ yum search java | grep 'java-'
```

If there are no available packages, then you may need to download a new repository to search through. I suggest taking a look at [Dag Wieers' repo](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B). After downloading it, try the above command again.

You will see at least one version of Java packages available for download. Depending on when you read this, the *lastest* available version may be different.

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

The above package alone will only install JRE. To also install `javac` and JDK, the following command will do the trick:

```
$ yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk*
```

These packages will be installing (as well as their dependencies):

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-accessibility.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch
java-1.7.0-openjdk-src.x86_64
```

Comment: Tested on CentOS 6.5. `sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64` installs only JRE(`javac` will be absent). `sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel` installs JDK.

Comment: I can confirm this also works on older versions of CentOS (I just ran the `yum install` command on 5.6).

Comment: After Installation: configuring iptables on centos 6.5 -> /etc/sysconfig/iptables -> -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Comment: @ThammeGowda - Thanks for pointing out, your suggestion works fine

Comment: @ThammeGowdaN I submitted an edit including your instructions.

Comment: Tested and confirmed on CentOS 7.

Comment: I also used `sudo alternatives --config java` to update the PATH

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to let anybody know, if needed, that this worked inside a CentOS docker container which already had java.

Answer (score 34):

@Sventeck, perfecto.

redhat docs are always a great source - good tutorial that explains how to install JDK via yum and then setting the path can be found here (have fun!) - [Install OpenJDK and set $JAVA_HOME path](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Installation_Guide/Install_OpenJDK_on_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux.html)

OpenJDK 6:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
```

OpenJDK 7:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

To list all available java openjdk-devel packages try:

```
yum list "java-*-openjdk-devel"
```

Comment: Tested on CentOS 6.4, I confirm it is the "centos" way. The JAVA_HOME environment variable should be set on "/etc/alternatives/jre".

Comment: Gotta love me some centos! This variable can also be stored in /etc/environment which is where most system wide global variables should exist.

`echo JAVA_HOME="path/to/JAVA_HOME" >> /etc/environment`

Answer (score 18):

`yum install java-1.8.0`

and then:

```
alternatives --config java
```

and check:

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 13):

On centos 7, I just do

`sudo yum install java-sdk`

I assume you have most common repo already.
Centos just finds the correct SDK with the -devel sufix.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative answer is,

```
sudo yum list \*java-1\* | grep open
```

than select one from list and install that

for example,

```
sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

Answer (score 6):

[**Here**](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=jdk) is a detailed information on setting up Java and its paths on CentOS6.

Below steps are for the installation of latest Java version 8:

1. Download java rpm package from [**Oracle site**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). (**jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm**)
2. Install from the rpm. (**rpm -Uvh jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm**)
3. Open **/etc/profile**, and set the java paths, save it.
4. Check the java installation path, and java version, with the commands: **which java**, **java -version**

Now you can test the installation with a sample java program

Answer (score 3):

Since Oracle inserted some md5hash in their download links, one cannot automatically assemble a download link for command line.

So I tinkered some nasty bash command line to get the latest jdk download link, download it and directly install via rpm.
For all who are interested:

> wget -q http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html -O ./index.html && grep -Eoi ']+>' index.html | grep -Eoi '/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-[0-9]+.html' | (head -n 1) | awk '{print "http://www.oracle.com"$1}' | xargs wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=xxx; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" -O index.html -q && grep -Eoi '"filepath":"[^"]+jdk-8u[0-9]+-**linux-x64.rpm**"' index.html | grep -Eoi 'http:[^"]+' | xargs wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=xxx; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" -q -O ./jdk8.rpm && sudo rpm -i ./jdk8.rpm

The **bold part** should be replaced by the package of your liking.

Comment: Righteous hack.

Comment: I've used a similar approach in a bash script to get the latest JRE and JDK download links for version 8 and 9. It can be found in [this thread as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49780226/6771046).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Oracle JDK and are willing not to use yum/rpm, see this answer here:

[Downloading Java JDK on Linux via wget is shown license page instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-installation-of-java-jdk-on-linux)

As per that post, you can automate the download of the tarball using curl and specifying a cookie header.

Then you can put the tarball contents in the right place and add java to your PATH, for example:

```
curl -v -j -k -L -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz > jdk.tar.gz

tar xzvf jdk.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/local/java
sudo mv jdk1.8.0_45 /usr/local/java/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45 /usr/local/java/jdk

sudo vi /etc/profile.d/java.sh
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/java/jdk/bin"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk

source /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below commands to install oracle java8 through terminal

Step -1) Visit Oracle JDK download page, look for RPM version

Step -2) Download oracle java 8 using the below command
         wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"   http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u121-b13/e9e7ea248e2c4826b92b3f075a80e441/jdk-8u121-linux-x64.rpm

Step -3) Install the java8 using below command
         sudo yum localinstall jdk-8u121-linux-x64.rpm
         Now the JDK should be installed at 
         /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121
Step -4) Remove the downloaded .rpm file to utilize the space.
         rm jdk-8u121-linux-x64.rpm

Step -5) Verify the java by using command 
          java -version

Step -6) If the CentOS has multiple JDK installed, you can use the alternatives command to set the default java 
        sudo alternatives --config java

Step -7)Optional set JAVA_HOME Environment variables.
       copy the path of jdk install i.e /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121
       use below command to export java home
       export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121
       export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

I have written a shell script to install/uninstall java on centos.
You can get it done by just run the shell.
The core of this shell is :

```
1.download the jdk rpm(RedHat Package Manager) package.
2.install java using rpm.
```

You can see more detail here:
https://github.com/daikaixian/WaterShell/tree/master/program_installer

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what I did:

1. First, I downloaded the `.tar` file for Java JDK and JRE from the Oracle site.
2. Extract the `.tar` file into the opt folder.
3. I faced an issue that despite setting my environment variables, `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` for Java 9, it was still showing Java 8 as my runtime environment. Hence, I symlinked from the Java 9.0.4 directory to `/user/bin` using the `ln` command.
4. I used `java -version` command to check which version of java is currently set as my default java runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

To install OpenJDK 8 JRE using yum with non root user, run this command:

> sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk

to verify 
java -version