# Installing JRE in centOS securely

Tags: centos, java

When I try to connect to the java site to pull the data I use:

'wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u25-b15/jre-7u25-linux-x64.rpm'

Then receive the error:

'ERROR: certificate common name âwww.oracle.comâedelivery.oracle.comâ
                                                                    To connect to edelivery.oracle.com insecurely, use â--no-check-certificateâ.'

When you go to install java you have to accept the license agreement. I think this is what is going wrong. Does anyone know how to accept this agreement if this is the issue. Or if this isnt this issue, what the problem is and a possible solution.

Comment: Possible dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-instalation-of-java-jdk-on-linux

You may try the command:
wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u25-b15/jre-7u25-linux-x64.rpm --no-check-certificate

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the rpm with the command:

wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u25-b15/… --no-check-certificate

(Possible duplicate of: [Downloading Java JDK on Linux via wget is shown license page instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-instalation-of-java-jdk-on-linux))