# How to handle quotes in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-installation-of-java-jdk-on-linux/10959815#10959815) I am able to get a wget url for the oracle jdk.
I intend to use it in a script vis

```
wget_opts="-c --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header --load-cookies="Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie""
jdk_download_url="http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz"

/usr/bin/wget $wget_opts $jdk_download_url
```

When I echo the above command it appears ok and is able to correctly download the file.
But on running the command in the script I get the below

```
--2014-06-04 14:19:43--  http://oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie%22/
Resolving oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"”
--2014-06-04 14:20:03--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com...
```

Wget gets the wrong URL.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
wget_opts='-c --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header --load-cookies="Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"'
jdk_download_url="http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz"

/usr/bin/wget $wget_opts $jdk_download_url
```

Check the difference between single and double quotes in [the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting).

**EDIT:** In fact you have some mistakes in your wget command line. Here is the correct line.

```
OPTS="-c --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header Cookie:oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
URL="http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz"

wget $OPTS $URL
```

The `--load-cookies` option take **a file** as argument **and not a string**. We have to use the `--header` option with `Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie`. After tests, I have seen that `wget` does not care about spaces in the header field. So we can use directly `Cookie:oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie`

If you use the `--debug` option you will see the correct formatted request :

```
GET /otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=5307-
User-Agent: Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: download.oracle.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie
```

Comment: @jml No, it doesn't, at least not in bash 3.2.25. It gets expanded to this:  `/usr/bin/wget -c --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header '--load-cookies="Cookie:' 'oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"' http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Answer (score 5):

Use an array:

```
wget_opts=( -c 
            --no-check-certificate 
            --no-cookies 
            --header 
            --load-cookies="Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" 
          )
jdk_download_url="http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u55-b13/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz"

# use the exact quoting below
/usr/bin/wget "${wget_opts[@]}" "$jdk_download_url"
```

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time

Comment: @glenn with that I get

"line 30: -c --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header --load-cookies="Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie": command not found"

Comment: What shell are you using to run this script? Use bash or ksh

Comment: @glenn. I use bash.  I have corrected a small error. The wget get run nicely but the header doesn't  get picked since the download link redirects to an error page. The error page is coz of no correct header.

Comment: does it matter if I have
wget=/usr/bin/wget  
if  ! $wget "${wget_opts[@]}" "$jdk_download_url"; then
. . . . . .

Comment: @glennjackman works fine.  but went jml's answer as it is simpler

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the double quotes that are within other double quotes:

```
wget_opts="-c --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header --load-cookies=\"Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie\""
```

Or enclose the string in single quotes if you don't need variable interpolation:

```
wget_opts='-c --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header --load-cookies="Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"'
```

Also, in your command, you need a `$` in front of `jdk_download_url`:

```
/usr/bin/wget $wget_opts $jdk_download_url
```

Comment: The missing $ was a type in the question. I have tried both of the above options without success.