# How to Install Java on CentOS 6.5

Tags: java, centos6.5

I am trying to download and install Java from oracle on CentOS6.5 but i am getting error. The command i am using is:

wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie:gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com""http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm"

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automate download and installation of Java JDK on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-installation-of-java-jdk-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies –header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm
--2015-03-03 22:13:44--  http://%E2%80%93header/
Resolving –header... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “–header”

Comment: wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies –header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm
--2015-03-03 22:13:44--  http://%E2%80%93header/
Resolving –header... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “–header”
--2015-03-03 22:13:44--  ftp://cookie/%20gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com
           => “ gpw_e24=http:%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com”

Comment: Resolving cookie... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “cookie”
--2015-03-03 22:13:44--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm
Resolving download.oracle.com... 184.25.56.42, 184.25.56.53
Connecting to download.oracle.com|184.25.56.42|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm [following]

Comment: --2015-03-03 22:13:44--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com... 69.192.197.85
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com|69.192.197.85|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]

Comment: --2015-03-03 22:13:45--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com|184.25.56.42|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: “jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm.1”

100%[======================================>] 5,307       --.-K/s   in 0s

2015-03-03 22:13:45 (197 MB/s) - “jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm.1” saved [5307/5307]

FINISHED --2015-03-03 22:13:45--
Downloaded: 1 files, 5.2K in 0s (197 MB/s)