# Download OracleXE Using wget

Tags: oracle, wget

How can I download OracleXE using wget and avoid the login?

I tried applying logic from [this question for Oracle Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/downloading-java-jdk-on-linux-via-wget-is-shown-license-page-instead) but I couldn't get it to work.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle11g/xe/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1 .0.x86_64.rpm.zip
```

I get:

```
--2015-10-13 04:51:03--  http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle11g/xe/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 206.248.168.160, 206.248.168.139, 206.248.168.160, ...
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|206.248.168.160|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/akam/otn/linux/oracle11g/xe/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip [following]
--2015-10-13 04:51:03--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/akam/otn/linux/oracle11g/xe/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.9.117.183, 23.9.117.183
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.9.117.183|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://login.oracle.com/pls/orasso/orasso.wwsso_app_admin.ls_login?Site2pstoreToken=v1.2~CA55CD32~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following]
--2015-10-13 04:51:03--  https://login.oracle.com/pls/orasso/orasso.wwsso_app_admin.ls_login?Site2pstoreToken=v1.2~CA55CD32~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
Resolving login.oracle.com (login.oracle.com)... 209.17.4.8, 209.17.4.8
Connecting to login.oracle.com (login.oracle.com)|209.17.4.8|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2051 (2.0K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip’

100%[======================================================================================================================================================>] 2,051       --.-K/s   in 0s

2015-10-13 04:51:03 (142 MB/s) - ‘oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip’ saved [2051/2051]
```

Comment: You can't *avoid* the login; you have to have an Oracle account to get the file. But you can script it in a similar way - Oracle used to even supply a wget script for some downloads, and I still have a variation somewhere that I use when I need to grab something like this and don't have a browser available. But that won't work unless you have an account still. And if you do, another approach is to just to use a browser on the target box, over X11 if necessary.

Comment: I'm open to creating an account. I tried wget with --username and --password but that didn't work. Can you post your script as an answer please.

Answer (score 1):

For download oracle for linux zips from url to directly server you have to:

1 - login Oracle.com with credentials..  (https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp)

2 - export cookie.txt with browser

3 - copy this file to your Server

```
scp cookies.txt  root@url:/path/
```

4 - go to path where your cookies.txt and copy install link and paste as to this to your server terminal

```
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt  http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle12c/121020/linuxamd64_12102_database_1of2.zip

wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle12c/121020/linuxamd64_12102_database_2of2.zip
```

check file size  with   `ls -lah`

Comment: I am automating a process so unfortunately, logging in with a browser is not viable.

Comment: ok. may be you can use this cookie on automation process permanently

Comment: The cookies expire after a few months I believe

Comment: Thanks, it saves my life, my operation details click here：
http://www.cnblogs.com/stevenlii/p/8580123.html

Answer (score 0):

Note, that `wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"` breaks all other cookies, including authorization ones.

Instead You can use custom cookies.txt file and --user/--password (tested on Oracle Archive and OracleXE)

```
echo .oracle.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   0   oraclelicense   accept-securebackup-cookie >cookies.txt
wget -c --load-cookies cookies.txt --trust-server-names --user=SSO_USERNAME --password=SSO_PASSWORD URL
```

UPD: Attention! cookies.txt is tab-separated! To be sure of tabs please use  `echo -e .oracle.com\tTRUE\t/\tFALSE\t0\toraclelicense\taccept-securebackup-cookie >cookies.txt