# Ansible - Java JDK install - Bypassing Login Requirement

Tags: java, automation, ansible

Some of our internal systems use older versions of Java, and it seems that some versions (in this case, 8u72) force users to log in before they can download the tarballs. We typically use Ansible to automate the whole process, but that's now being tripped by the login requirement. Has anyone managed to find a workaround for this, or a reliable mirror?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not download the required JDK rpm file(s) you need and either include them with the playbook, or store them on a common webserver inside your network and download from there?  This is idempotent and you know exactly which RPM was installed.  Plus the link that @Zlemini references has many updates when Oracle changes something on their server side.

Answer (score 4):

To download it you need to add a custom HTTP header which accepts a license, here is is how it looks in Ansible using the `get_url` module

```
- name: Download JDK
  get_url:
    url: "{{ jdk_url }}.rpm"
    headers: 'Cookie:oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie'
    dest: "/tmp/{{ jdk_pkg }}.rpm"
```

More info here: [Downloading Java JDK on Linux via wget is shown license page instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/downloading-java-jdk-on-linux-via-wget-is-shown-license-page-instead)

Comment: Unfortunately that's just the license acceptance. That's in place and works without a problem on the more recent releases, but older versions still request a login afterwards (https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp). Thanks though!

Comment: Right @seanhillen, I've experienced the same. For former/old/outdated versions (aka Java Archive Downloads) it would be necessary to have an Oracle account and to login. You may find reliable mirrors at some university FTP servers all over the world (.edu/.org).

Answer (score 0):

Have found this solution, if it can help you

```
 - name: Create JAVA_HOME folder
    file: state=directory path={{global_vars.home_path}}/java owner=dev group=dev recurse=yes mode=0755

  - name: Download Java from url
    command: "wget -q -O {{global_vars.home_path}}/java/jdk-linux-x64.tar.gz --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header 'Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' {{global_vars.java_download_url}} creates={{global_vars.home_path}}/java/jdk-linux-x64.tar.gz"
    register: java_out
    when:
```