# From command line download latest Java SE Runtime Environment 8 on Windows

Tags: java, windows, powershell, wix, silent

On a Windows server, I am looking for a robust way to download latest Java SE Runtimes from command-line .

My requirement is to check if java is installed on the system.
If java is not found, our MSI installer (created with WIX) need to connect oracle java download page and silently download java installer in the background and invoke the installer silently. 
Download option can be in VB script/PowerShell/batch/Java

Installing java silently is easy with `jre-8u121-windows-x64.exe /s`option.

I could find couple of solutions to download jre on *nix with curl/wget
[from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/downloading-java-jdk-on-linux-via-wget-is-shown-license-page-instead)

However, couldn't find any robust solution on Windows.

Please let me know is there a fool proof way to download JRE installer on Windows from command line.

Comment: Visit the oracle site and download JRE 8 and install

Comment: Looking for download option from command line.

Comment: We have simple solution why you have go for harder like download from command prompt .. this is my suggestion...

Comment: I am aware of the simple option and do it most of the time. However, the requirement is to do it from command line(pity on me).

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org), its simple, easy and handles all the pain for you (like keeping up with the new versions or when the link changes, etc)

Comment: i would recommend chocolatey too. Its super easy and fun.

Answer (score 1):

cmd.exe /c "MD C:\Install-temp&bitsadmin /transfer Download /download /priority high https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=236886_42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60 c:\Install-temp\Java.exe&start /wait c:\Install-temp\Java.exe /s & RD c:\Install-temp /S /Q"

Comment: Hi there, please complement your answer to provide a better explanation of what this script really does.