# Unable to download jdk-7u71-linux-x64.rpm using wget, tried almost everything from forum

Tags: java, linux, wget, java-7

I am trying to download jdk-7u71-linux-x64.rpm in a linux box using wget, so that I could use that command later in some bash script to download jdk wherever the script is executed.

Tried different ways using : --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header

One of them is : wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u71-b14/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.rpm

Nothing worked! (Old answers are not working anymore)

Is there a way to download older JDK like 7u71?

Comment: Looks like Oracle redirects to authorization page before download. You can check it by visiting http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u71-b14/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.rpm

Comment: @jahra yeah, that's why I am looking for some answers here.
It is really required for me to download this particular version, that too using wget command.
Any way we can do this?

Comment: Basically, Oracle doesn't like people doing that.  They want you to go to the website and click the button that says that you agree to the conditions.  And they keep changing the way that the web page works.  Whether they are doing it deliberately or not is unclear.  But the obvious solution is to ... just do what they want you to do.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/downloading-java-jdk-on-linux-via-wget-is-shown-license-page-instead#10959815

Comment: Is this for use just within one organisation? If so, you could just download it once and store it on an internal server, and then copy/download it from there.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal yes I did went through that link, but nothing helped.
it's all old methods before oracle changed its download link format.

Comment: Nice suggestion @RobinGreen !
though is there a way we can do what I am looking for?

Answer (score -2):

You can also install java using tar file.

Download jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz tar file from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

Go to download location, open terminal to untar the downloaded file using command

**tar -zxvf jdk-7u71***

Check whether jdk1.7.0_71 folder is created or not?

Update JAVA_HOME and PATH variable in bashrc using commands

**vi ~/.bashrc**

Append these two variables at last

**export JAVA_HOME=*pathtodownloads*/jdk1.7.0_71**

**export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH**

save and exit vi-editor

do execute **source ~/.bashrc** in terminal

Check java installation with
**java -version**

Comment: bro, OP is asking to download rpm using wget not via browser

Comment: Yeah, by browser I can do that, even I placed jdk file manually using filezilla! But I am in need of getting it downloaded by command!(to use it in bash file)