# AWS - How to install java11 on an EC2 Linux machine?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, java-11

I tried this

[Downloading Java JDK on Linux via wget is shown license page instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/downloading-java-jdk-on-linux-via-wget-is-shown-license-page-instead)

but I keep getting a 404 error.

This command  "sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11" just states that amazon-linux-extras doesnt exist.

Comment: amazon-linux-extras is only available on Amazon Linux 2 (and does work). If you're using a different Linux distribution, then you have to use one of the other suggested options below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use one of the OpenJDK distributions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html

or

https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot

Answer (score 67):

Another option might be running the following commands:

In order to install **java 11:**

`sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11`

For **java 8** you can try:

`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`

Finally, if you want to switch between java versions run:

`sudo alternatives --config java`

Comment: This is a faster alternative answer, upvoted!

Comment: This works only if you open up outbound https in your Security Group assigned to your EC2 instance!  lol

Comment: I need to install java 11 in aws code build virtual machine and its not working for me. OS details Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS architecture 4.14.275-207.503.amzn2.x86_64

Answer (score 15):

Sharing my simple working approach

**Downloading the JDK**

`curl -LO https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-11-x64-linux-jdk.tar.gz`

**note:** check the ec2 instance's platform ie., x64, aarch64, x86, aarch32 etc.,because the wrong platform jdk installation will leads to `/bin/java: /bin/java: cannot execute binary file`

**Extracting the JDK to /usr/java/**

```
sudo tar -xvzf amazon-corretto-11-x64-linux-jdk.tar.gz -C /usr/java/
```

**Run the below single line command to change the soft link for java files in (/usr/bin) directory**

```
cd /usr/java/amazon-corretto-*-linux-x64/bin
for i in java javac jfr; do path=$(find `pwd`/$i -type f); echo $path; sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/$i $i $path 20000 ; sudo update-alternatives --config $i ; done
```

after the above command execution, there will be a command prompt that will ask you to choose the selection number which represents the file residing path and we should choose the number which refers to path `/usr/java/amazon-corretto-*-linux-x64/bin/`

The amazon-corretto jdk version may vary based on the timeline that you download. Currently the java version is `11.0.12.7.1`

That's it execute `java -version`, you can see the java version as

```
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.12.7.1 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.12.7.1 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Comment: love the detail here, thanks!

Comment: Amazing explanation . Worked well for me. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

below documents can be followed from AWS to install JAVA 11 in EC2 instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/amazon-linux-install.html

sudo yum install java-11-amazon-corretto-devel

Answer (score 0):

I tried `sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11` but that didn't install tools like `jstatd` and `jps`.  I had better luck installing Corretto using these instructions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/amazon-linux-install.html

Answer (score 0):

## How to install Java 21 on Amazon Linux 2 base image:

To install the [Amazon Corretto JDK](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto) onto the [Amazon Linux 2](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2) docker image ([aws-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-cli)), this works for me (within a bitbucket pipeline):

```
curl -fL -o corretto.rpm https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-21-x64-linux-jdk.rpm
yum localinstall -y corretto.rpm
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-amazon-corretto
```