# Install Java on Cent OS

Tags: java, linux, centos

I want to install JAVA on centOs. I followed the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901442/how-to-install-jdk-in-centos) but its for openJDK. What i want to install is the Oracle version of it.

Then i followed the this [article](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux), and was unable to add the path as shown in point 10 of the article.

I think i am looking at the wrong resources to install java on CentOS, therefore can someone please help me install it by giving me steps.

Comment: I would give it a try this http://askubuntu.com/a/55960/18075 It is for ubuntu installation but I think you can install it on centos quite similar...

Answer (score 2):

Use the following steps:

Download the installation package (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959815/3618339):

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/jdk-7u55-linux-x64.rpm
```

Install the package:

```
rpm -Uvh jdk-7u55-linux-x64.rpm
```

That's all you need.

Comment: Java 8 is out. Why install rpm for 7u55?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just replace *7u55* with *8u5* in both commands.

Comment: What about setting path to JAVA_HOME ? Are these done automatically ?

Comment: There's no need to set JAVA_HOME. There will be an executable binary *java* in /usr/bin, which is sufficiently intelligent to find all the necessary directories of the Java environment.