# How do I install Java OpenJDK 1.6.0_36 to CentOS 7.2

Tags: java, linux, centos

I want to download Java version "1.6.0_36" in CentOS. I tried `sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk`, but it returned Java version 1.6.0_41. How do I install a specific version?

Can it be downloaded from the terminal directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Jdk in centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901442/how-to-install-jdk-in-centos)

Comment: By the way, be aware that [Java 16 reaches end-of-life in October](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html). Supplanted by Java 17 that came out mid-September. Java 17 is designated a [Long Term Support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version.

Comment: @BasilBourque sure.. but this question is about 1.6 (aka 6). That's been EOL for years already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a specific version hosted from CentOS archive server.

1. Update first `elrepo`, to make sure that you will have the latest RPM repository for CentOS.

```
sudo yum update elrepo
```

2. Then install the specific version from CentOS archive.

```
sudo yum install https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.01.u/java-1.6.0-openjdk/20150730180723/1.6.0.36-1.13.8.1.el7_1.x86_64/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.36-1.13.8.1.el7_1.x86_64.rpm
```

> **Note:** This server contains a mix of raw/unsigned packages and/or build logs.
> It should be used mainly for testing purposes.

Comment: holy smokes! it actually worked for me. i wasnt able to update this "elrepo" though. thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You can download [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html) and search for Java SE Runtime Environment 6u41

Comment: thanks!
can it be downloaded from the terminal directly?

Comment: It's a specific version. You can download it form the link and use this command to 
install it.  `sudo yum localinstall <file>.rpm` about the command you can have a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/940791/whats-the-difference-between-yum-install-local-path-and-yum-localinstall).

Comment: hi @tpnoon is there a 36 version? what i currently have is tha 41 version

Comment: I saw versions 35 and 37. I think it's not supported by Oracle