# Updating jdk on Google Compute Engine

Tags: java, hadoop, google-compute-engine, centos6, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to have to update my JDK on an instance in Google compute. Basically I am looking to get Hortonworks Hadoop up and running and based on the [instructions here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-2.html).

I need:

> Your system must have the correct JDK installed on all the nodes of the cluster. HDP supports the following JDKs.
>   Oracle JDK 1.6 update 31 64-bit
>   Oracle JDK 7 64-bit
>   OpenJDK 7 64-bit

I created an instance and installed Centos 6.5 and when I check the Java version it says:

```
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
```

How do I update it to 1.6? Or the versions listed above? I see instructions everywhere on how to update to a local system. However, I don't see instructions on updating on a Google compute instance.

Comment: check the jdk rpm's installed and remove and replace them. else download jdk and include it in you PATH

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104817/how-to-install-java-sdk-on-centos ?