# Maven Trying to compile in Linux environment using command line : No compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am trying to generate a build using maven, So started with 
mvn clean package command in linux server and Getting error as follows:

```
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than
a JDK?
```

I searched and found some solutions so changed my JAVA_HOME path etc.
And following is my settings

- My JAVA_HOME => `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/jre`
- MVN VERSION SHOWS: `Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)`
- Maven home: `/home/ec2-user/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current`
- Java version: `1.7.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation`
- Java home: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/jre`
- OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.51-40.58.amzn1.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"**

MY POM.XML File as follows:
[image]

Comment: yes changed and tried. still getting the same error

Comment: you need to install jdk first , you are just running jre. please install jdk using sudo apt-get install java , or add webupd PPA to install Oracle Java

Comment: oh let me try that way. thanks new to java thats the problem for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My JAVA_HOME => /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/jre

By this I assume you mean setting an environmental variable.  Mine is set to the directory right above yours.  I'd try that.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64
```

Mine is set like the following which may not work for you but is here as an example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

When I `ls` that directory I get the following.  You should get something similar.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION  docs     jre  man      THIRD_PARTY_README
bin                 include  lib  src.zip
```

Comment: Thanks [~gray] and [~satya] I installed the JDK and Eventually it works.

Comment: Tested on CentOS 6.5. sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 installs only JRE(javac will be absent). sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel installs JDK. from http://stackoverflow.com/a/12792019/744478

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because on many reasons:

1. If you haven't installed the JDK package. For example, you have installed java-11-openjdk.x86_64 but JDK comes with a development package. For instance, java-11-openjdk-devel.x86_64 is a java jdk package. It always comes with the extension **devel**.
2. Inappropriate java versions, like a project that requires java 17 but we may have installed java 11.