# How to create WAR file in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, war

I have maven based project. I want to create WAR file. I have eclipse (Version: Helios Service Release 2). 
*What are the steps to create WAR file?
*Where to give WAR name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108019/how-to-make-war-file-in-eclipse

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files) might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is maven-based project then :
1)Right click on your project.
2) Choose Run-as
3) Select Maven install 
4) Check the console for Build failure or success .

Your WAR file of a project is generated into the target folder.

Answer (score 2):

Right click your project name in the project explorer panel. On the popup menu, go to Export, you will see the War file menu item

Comment: It's under the "Web" category in the export menu.