# Compile a project in eclipse, get a war or ear or jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, war, ear

Well, I has a doubt about compiling a java project into eclipse.

**Note:** *My project is not using maven.*

If i want to get a **.ear** or **.jar** or **.war** file
what is the way?

I want to compile my project and get all compilation errors, because I change my jdk version, from jdk 1.5 to jdk 1.8

And this is why I want to compile it getting my compilaion errors, to fix them and get the ear or war files

I mean, may I compile from 
project -> clean -> built automatically

And this gonna give me this kind of files?

Or i have to compile it from command prompt?

Hope you can help me, any idea is a good one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make war file in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108019/how-to-make-war-file-in-eclipse)

Comment: @John Kane I added some explanation about my question, you're right I was no giving clear one about what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project > Export > Runnable JAR file or just JAR file.

From there you have many options concerning libraries: extract them, pack them, or just put them aside the generated jar.

Comment: Yep that helps, but when I do it, I'm not able to get my compilation errors...
Maybe something wrong In my eclipse configuration?